# What does it mean "cab" in the context of a centrifuge?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have a centrifuge manual that mentions the word 'cab' in a context of the centrifuge.  I checked the entries in the dictionaries and I can't think of one of the definitions there (such as taxi etc.) as a relevant definition for this context.

> "It is the condition which **cab** can be memorized".
>    [image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case, it's just a typo for **can**. Judging from the rest of the text, it was not written by a native speaker. Most of the sentences are awkward at best.

**However,** there **is** a meaning of "cab" which can be applied to *manned centrifuges* like this one, which is used by the U.S. Air Force to [train flight crew for g-tolerance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-G_training):

[image: US Air Force centrifuge]

Here, the **cab** is the part of the centrifuge where the occupant sits (the compartment on the left in the photo above, with the stairs leading up to it). This is a shortening of **cabin** and is sometimes used in engineering contexts, especially aerospace and military.

Example usage in the wild:

> Mounted on the machine are three enclosed cabs (7.6 ft x 5.9 ft x 6.8 ft). One cab, mounted at one end of the rotating arm, contains a modified jet fighter seat in which a human sits during tests. A second cab, at the other end of the rotating arm, is often used for non-human subjects. This cab contains a swing frame and can be configured to meet an investigator's needs. ([NASA](https://www.nasa.gov/ames/research/space-biosciences/20-g-centrifuge))